# Change parent state ID and reload child state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Say I have three states:

```
.state('client', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/client/{id}',   
    template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state('form', {
    parent: 'client',
    url: '/form',  
    templateUrl: 'app/submit/submission.html',
    controller: 'submissionsController',
    controllerAs: 'qa',
})
.state('view', {
    parent: 'client',
    url: '/view',        
    templateUrl: 'app/design/view/viewer.html',
    controller: 'formViewerController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        formsMeta: function(rubricsService, userService){
            return rubricsService.fetchActiveRubricsQuestionsMeta(userService.selectedClientId);
        }
    }         
})
```

I can have `/client/5/view` or `/client/5/form`. I have a drop down in my navbar where the user can change the client at any time. I want to be able to be able to change the state from `/client/5/view` to `/client/10/view` with the dropdown, triggering a state change that handles all the child's resolves...etc.

How can I change just the parent's state with a different ID and refresh whatever child state the user is currently in?